# multiple positions exist in multiple region

Tags: python, for-loop, position, variant

I have a variant position file and an exon region file.

```
1   242600263 
12  54757526  
11  45853978
```

The exon region file looks like this.

```
1:11861218-11861456 MTHFR-001_2
22:44280101-44280243   PNPLA5-201_7
```

Both files have around 100,000 lines.

For now, I write the exon region file into one dictionary, using the region as key.

When looping through the variant file, check if this position located in any key of exon dictionary.

```
for i in F1: <- loop through exon file 
    chrpos, exon, check=i
    exondict[chrpos]=exon

for j in F2: <- loop through variant file
    chr=j[0]
    if chr=="11": <- get chr 11 first
        variant=j[1]
        for chrpos in exondict.keys():
            chr, pos= chrpos.split(':')
            start, stop= pos.split('-')
            chr, start, stop
            if int(start)<=int(variant)<=int(stop):
                 newlist=[exondict[chrpos]]+ j
                 W.writerow(newlist)
```

Basically, I got what I want.

Just wondering if there is more elegant way to do this.

Thank you!

For example, a variant position is chr11:108164047 which locates within 11:108164040-108164204 ATM-201_31.

Comment: It's not efficient doing that splitting and int conversion in the inner loop. So instead of using the string as the key, split it into a tuple, and use the tuple as the key, eg `'1:11861218-11861456'` -> `(1, 11861218, 11861456)`. There are probably further improvements that can be made, but that should speed things up noticeably.

Comment: Can you post an example of your successful output so we can try to replicate?